# What is the role of the application server in javamail functionalities?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have an inbox application, jsf web application, using javamail at the business layer and JAMES3 as a mailserver. Actually i didn't find any benefit from deploying my application in glassfish at the level of messaging. Does anybody know what are the benefits of the session created in application server ?

Is there any reference or pdf or something like tutorial to illustrate everything related to javamail in enterprise environmet not standard one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application server manages the JavaMail Session object for you as an administered object, allowing you to reconfigure it without changing your application code.  Of course, this depends on you accessing the Session as a Java EE resource, e.g., using @Resource to inject it.

Comment: I mean what benefit could i gain from the session being created and managed by the application server, other than remote configuration. I can imagine application server to do very more than this when i map it to the mailserver.

Comment: at the authentication level, the authenticator is taken by the session in constructor, but in case of app server injecton, how can that be... i just need a reference for such issues, i didnt find in the whole net any thing related to working with javamail in enterprise environmet... can u help?

Comment: Ideally, the application server would configure the Session with an Authenticator that supplies the username and password that are configured for the managed session.  I can't say for sure that all application servers do that correctly, but if they don't you should file a bug.  I believe there should be some examples in the Java EE SDK and/or the Java EE tutorial.

Comment: then , what does the MailSessionDefinition and MailSessionDefinitions annotations do?